# Is there a way to get channels by name? (Discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was creating a lock command where the channel name/id would be passed as the 1st argument. The command use case would be something like this: `.lock #[channel-name]/[channel_id]`. This works with a channel id, however, it returns `undefined` when I attempt to use a channel name instead (e.g `.lock #test`). Would there be a way to achieve this?

```js
const channel =
 bot.channels.cache.find(
  (channel) => channel.name == `#${args.slice(0).join('-')}`
 ) || bot.channels.cache.get(args[0]);

if (!channel) {
 console.log(channel);
 return message.reply('Please provide a channel name/id!');
}

if (!args[1]) {
 return message.reply('Please set the lock type!');
}

if (!channel.permissionsFor(message.guild.roles.everyone).has('VIEW_CHANNEL')) {
 const errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(
   `❌ \`VIEW_CHANNEL\` for \`${channel.name}\` is already disabled.`
  )
  .setColor('RED');
 return message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
}
channel
 .updateOverwrite(channel.guild.roles.everyone, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false })
 .then(() => {
  const msgEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(`✅ The channel\`${channel.name}\` has been locked.`)
   .setColor('GREEN');
  message.channel.send(msgEmbed);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
  const errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(`❌ Unable to lock \`${channel.name}\`.`)
   .setColor('RED');
  message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`discord.js` parses channel mentions (`#channel-name`) as `<#channelID>`, not `#channel-name.`

---

You can use:

```js
bot.channels.cache.get(args[0].match(/<#(\d+)>/)[1])
```

to get a channel from a mention.